# Delphi - ADOTable does not delete records properly and creates ghost records

Tags: database, delphi, dbgrid

I need  help fixing a problem with my database. I have a .mdb file that contains records of cars. This is linked to my ADOTable and then a DBGrid in Delphi. When I delete records via a button on my form, it appears to not delete it properly, because when i scroll through the dbgrid, the active record is suppose to change/update ***(depends whether i am scrolling down or up)*** and display the value of each field of the active record in edits below the DBGrid.

After my code deleted the record, It does not appear in the DBGrid or in the .mdb-file when I view it in MS Access, So I assumed it was properly deleted. But, like I explained above, when the ***OnMouseWheel*** event excecutes, it displays what i guess is either a deleted record, or the previous record's data when the pointer of the active record of the DBGrid clearly shows it should display the next or previous records data.

It is interesting to note that the OnCellClick and DBGridNavigator Buttons does not have this effect on the DBGrid and the record information displayed.

### Images:

***Before OnMouseWheel-event***
[image: Before OnMouseWheel-event]

***Each image after 1 excecution:***
[image]

[image]
***Image of the actual .mdb file:***
[image]

---

### Code for procedures and functions used:

***OnMouseWheel:***

```
procedure TCars.DBGrid1MouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; 
MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Show_Car_Details;
end;
```

***OnCellClick:***

```
procedure TCars.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
  Show_Car_Details;
end;
```

***Show_Car_Details:***

```
procedure TCars.Show_Car_Details;
begin
  with CarOwners.tbl_Cars do
  begin
    edt_Car_ID.text := inttostr(fieldbyname('ID').value);
    edt_Car_Type.text := fieldbyname('Make').value;
    edt_Car_Price.text := FloatToStr(fieldbyname('Price').value);
    edt_Car_Distance.text := inttostr(fieldbyname('Distance').value);
    edt_Owner_ID.text := inttostr(fieldbyname('OwnerID').value);

    if fieldbyname('Insurance').value = true then
    begin
      cbx_Insurance.ItemIndex := 0;
    end
    else
    begin
      cbx_Insurance.ItemIndex := 1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

***The Delete procedure:***

```
procedure TCars.bit_DeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if messagedlg
    ('Are you sure you want to delete this record? It will permanently be removed.',
    mtConfirmation, [mbyes, mbno], 0) <> mryes then
    exit;

  CarOwners.tbl_Cars.Delete;
  DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh;
end;
```

***Just incase, code for the Add and update procedures as well:***
***Add:***

```
procedure TCars.bit_AddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Make: string;
  OwnerID, Distance: Integer;
  Price: real;
  Insurance: Boolean;
begin
  Make := edt_Car_Type.text;
  OwnerID := strtoint(edt_Owner_ID.text);
  Distance := strtoint(edt_Car_Distance.text);
  Price := strtofloat(edt_Car_Price.text);
  if cbx_Insurance.ItemIndex = 0 then
  begin
    Insurance := true;
  end
  else
  begin
    Insurance := false;
  end;

  Add_Record(Make, OwnerID, Price, Distance, Insurance);
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------
procedure TCars.Add_Record(Make: string; OwnerID: Integer; Price: real;
  Distance: Integer; Insurance: Boolean);
begin

  // ----validation----
  //validation done here(removed for space, just basic if with exit.)

  // add new information
  with CarOwners do
  begin
    tbl_Cars.DisableControls;
    tbl_Cars.last;
    tbl_Cars.Insert;
    tbl_Cars['Make'] := Make;
    tbl_Cars['OwnerID'] := OwnerID;
    tbl_Cars['Price'] := Price;
    tbl_Cars['distance'] := Distance;
    tbl_Cars['Insurance'] := Insurance;
    tbl_Cars.post;
    tbl_Cars.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

***Update procedure:***

```
procedure TCars.bit_UpdateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Brand: string;
  Price: real;
  Insurance: Boolean;
  OwnerID, Distance: Integer;
begin
  Brand := edt_Car_Type.text;
  Price := strtofloat(edt_Car_Price.text);
  OwnerID := strtoint(edt_Owner_ID.text);
  Distance := strtoint(edt_Car_Distance.text);

  if cbx_Insurance.ItemIndex = 0 then
  begin
    Insurance := true;
  end
  else
  begin
    Insurance := false;
  end;

  Update_Record(Brand, OwnerID, Price, Distance, Insurance);
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TCars.Update_Record(Make: string; OwnerID: Integer; Price: real;
  Distance: Integer; Insurance: Boolean);
begin
  //validation done here(removed for space, just basic if with exit.)

  // ----Update Information ----
  with CarOwners do
  begin
    tbl_Cars.DisableControls;
    tbl_Cars.edit;
    tbl_Cars['Make'] := Make;
    tbl_Cars['OwnerID'] := OwnerID;
    tbl_Cars['Price'] := Price;
    tbl_Cars['Distance'] := Distance;

    if Insurance then
    begin
      tbl_Cars['Insurance'] := true;
    end
    else
    begin
      tbl_Cars['Insurance'] := false;
    end;
    // ShowMessage('Posting...');
    tbl_Cars.post;
    // ShowMessage('Done');
    tbl_Cars.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Any advice or assistance is welcome!!!
Regards

Comment: So, what is your question exactly? You should edit your post and add a MINIMALIST program which reproduce the issue without using any database we don't have to test.

Comment: You should link your fields directly to the datasource.

Comment: @Olivier, If i do that, then I will have no way to validate them. This is also part of a school Practical or PAT, which states that it has to be done via the edits. Sorry, i thought that that was useless info regarding my question and problem.

Comment: You can also use the [OnDataChange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.DB.TDataSource.OnDataChange) event to update the fields.

Comment: @Olivier, whould you mind explaining how that would solve my problem? I am still a bit of a noob :).

Comment: "Sorry, i thought that that was useless info regarding my question and problem."  Not at all.  In fact it explains why your code seems to be written without any regard to how to correctly write Delphi db-aware applications.  Tell your tutor that you don't need to use TEdits instead of TDBEdits just to do validation.  You can use the TField's OnValidate event to validate individual fields and the TDataSet Before Post event to do inter-field validation...

Comment: "you mind explaining how that would solve my problem" The `MouseWheel` event is not the right place where to refresh the field controls. If the method is called *before* the event is processed by the grid, then you end up displaying the previous record.

Comment: @Olivier:  Great explanation!  I think the OP should spend more time listening to you and less to his instructor.

Comment: I suggest you save yourself a lot of time and grief by googling yourself a decent tutorial on master-detail applications in Delphi.  Googling "delphi tutorial master-detail db-aware", [this](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/Master+Detail+Structures/) was the first hit and it looks quite good.

Comment: Could any of you give me an example of how to use OnDataChange? Thank you guys very much for the help so far. Yes, i know my tutor sucks, I am in public education, so i can't really expect anything different.

Comment: @MartynA, @Olivier, thank you so much for the help! The `OnDataChange` was the correct event to use! You guys saved my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MartynA and @Olivier for the answer. The problem was using the wrong event handler to refresh and display the record's field values.

DO NOT USE:
`OnMouseWheel`

USE:

```
procedure TCarOwners.ds_CarsDataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
  if Field = nil then
  begin
    Cars.show_car_details;
  end;
end;
```

This updates the non data-aware controls correctly. Be sure to add the `Form1` or in my case `Cars_frm` to the `uses` list directly under `implementation`.

Comment: More gernerally, when the behaviour you want is related to the data in the dataset, use the events of TDataSet and its descendants like TAdoDataSet, and of TField, rather than events in the GUI, to get the behaviour you want.